# iPhone: Capture iOS Camera with Overlay View

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application i am capturing picture through camera with overlay view & in the overlay view, there is a custom button through which i want to capture the whole screen.Overlay view is transparent at some points where i want to capture image. I am doing it like this:

```
    - (IBAction)captue:(id)sender
    {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
        [self.layer.presentationLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    }
```

It is capturing the image of overlay view but at the camera view (the view where overlay is transparent and i want to show camera view there) it is capturing black color instead of a photo. Anyone please tell me am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Using AVFoundationFramework to fix your problem.

Referred this link: http://code4app.net/ios/Camera-With-AVFoundation/5003cb1d6803fa9a2c000000

Answer (score -1):

I found Screen capture is the one of the thing to capture camera view with overlay. But i didn't get the preview layer in screen captured video(in case video recording). Look at [MyAVControllerDemo](https://github.com/benlodotcom/MyAVControllerDemo) code to get clear idea and i used [IAScreenCaptureView](https://github.com/adam-roth/screen-cap-view) to capture video, or simple snap shot. Now working properly.